# UICollectionView crashes randomly because of highlighting issue

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` on `iOS7` which crashes randomly when intense scrolling. I enabled zombies and found that it gives me an error saying:

```
*** -[NSIndexPath section]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x17dbc970
```

I believe this is due to an Apple error described [here](https://github.com/IgorTavcar/UICollectionViewBug). Apparently, the app crashes when someone highlights a cell while scrolling fast, and then the OS tries to unhighlight it when it moves off screen, when it ceases to exist. The proposed solution is to disable the `userInteractionEnabled` property of the cell and then handle the selection using `UIGestureRecogniser`.

Has anyone else faced this same issue? Also, I tried unsetting the `userInteractionEnabled` property and using a gesture recogniser, but this doesn't seem to work. Any idea how I can fix this?

**EDIT**: Code added on request

```
-(UICollectionViewCell*) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Gallery_Cell";

GalleryCell *cell= (GalleryCell *)[self.flowCollection dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (indexPath.row < self.collectionData.count) {

    CellDetails *dets = [self.collectionData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSURL *mainImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:dets.imageURL];

    cell.image.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    cell.image.clipsToBounds = YES;

    if ([[[SDWebImageManager sharedManager] imageCache] imageFromDiskCacheForKey:[self cacheKeyForURL:mainImageURL]] == nil) {

          [cell.image setImageWithURL:mainImageURL placeholderImage:nil];

    }else{

          [cell.image setImage:[[[SDWebImageManager sharedManager] imageCache] imageFromDiskCacheForKey:[self cacheKeyForURL:mainImageURL]]];

    }
}

return cell;
}
```

**EDIT**: more code..

I defined the `GalleryCell` for reuse as follows:

```
[self.flowCollection registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"Thumbs_Cell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Gallery_Cell"];
```

The GalleryCell class implementation is:

GalleryCell.h

```
@interface GalleryCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;

@end
```

GalleryCell.m

```
@implementation GalleryCell
@synthesize image;

-(void) setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted {
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];
    [self.image cancelCurrentImageLoad]; // SDWebImage method to cancel ongoing image load
}
```

Comment: Do you load a data to cells from Core Data? Possibly this crash happened when `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is working.

Comment: I am using SDWebImage to load images to the cells from the Internet.

Comment: So you should take care about use it because `UICollectionView` calls `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` each time the cell becomes visible.

Comment: Ok. But doesn't this have to do with the situation when the cell becomes invisible and gets deallocated? I turned off the userInteractionEnabled property, and the crash no longer occurs. This clearly has something to do with the highlighted state of the cell.

Comment: The log says that code tried to send message to **deallocated** instance. Keep in mind my remark about `UICollectionView` and check out the scenario.

Comment: First thing which became to my head is that `SDWebImage` tries to set image to hidden cell.

Comment: But why does the crash not occur when I set userInteractionEnabled to FALSE?

Comment: Also, I just commented out the SDWebImage code to disable the image loading and tried it again. The crash still occurs.

Comment: Show your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` implementation.

Comment: Added code as requested. Please check it out.

Comment: Can I see the definition for the GalleryCell class please?

Comment: @HelgeBecker. Added more code. Please check.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK. I seem to have solved it. In case anyone faces this problem, here is the fix:

I implemented the following method in my `UICollectionViewDelegate`:

```
-(BOOL) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView shouldHighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    return NO;
}
```

This prevents any cell from highlighting, and hence, avoids the crash when the system tries to unhighlight it when it goes off-screen. But, when you do this it also stops calling the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method. So I had to use a `UITapGestureRecogniser` method to implement cell selection instead.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I seem to be having the same issue, but only very rarely (and not reproducible in my dev environment). Rather than using a tap recogniser, have you considered checking if the indexPath is visible in `shouldHighlightItem...`. eg. `return [[collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems] containsObject:indexPath];`. I'm going to give it a go and hope it clears up issues my customers are seeing.

Comment: Hmm. I didn't really think along those lines, so I didn't check it like this. But the problem stopped occurring so I left it at this solution. But good luck with your approach!

Comment: Just to note, we were seeing the same crash in our crash analytics and in more than 3000 occurrences the device was running iOS 7. iOS 8 has 0 occurrences.

Comment: (I'm guessing no, because the defect is about the system unhighlighting the cells later, not about the app highlighting them.)

Comment: It would appear not... though I am still only seeing it in iOS7, so it seems to have been fixed in iOS 8. Seems to be an Apple bug.

Comment: I too am facing this problem in iOS 7. It is not reproducible and doesn't happen very often. I've seen maybe two crashes related to this. Also, only on iOS7. Will try out this approach to fix the issue, but not sure there is any merit in fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest returning the following:

```
- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView shouldHighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        return !collectionView.dragging && !collectionView.tracking;
}
```